# How can I create a datagrid validation dependency between columns

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, xaml, code-behind

I am trying to create a validation dependency between 2 datagrid columns.

The first column is a drop down box. (DataGridTemplateColumn)
The second is a text column. (DataGridTextColumn)

I am trying from the drop down box event in the code behind to force the validation of the datagrid text column cell of the same row.

Thanks for your help.

```
            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" >
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TypeListContainer}, Path=TypeLists}" Loaded="TypeBoxLoaded" DropDownClosed="TypeBoxChanged">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Rule" Binding="{Binding RuleWrapper, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" x:Name="RuleCol" />
```

Here is the property

```
public string RuleWrapper
{
    get
    {
        return this.Rule;
    }
    set
    {
        //Required
        if (value == null || value == string.Empty)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Rule is required");
        }
        //Match regular expression if type is channel
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(51[01]|50[0-9]|[0-4]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(51[01]|50[0-9]|[0-4]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(51[01]|50[0-9]|[0-4]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(51[01]|50[0-9]|[0-4]?[0-9][0-9]?)$");
        if (Type == "channel" && !reg.IsMatch(value))
            throw new ValidationException("Channel not matching the right format");

        //Match range if type is trunk
        int intValue = -1;
        //Match if is a number
        if (int.TryParse(value, out intValue))
        {
            //Match if number is in the range
            if (intValue < 0 || intValue > 134217727)
                throw new ValidationException("Trunk value must be between 0 and 134317727");
        }
        else
            throw new ValidationException("Trunk value must a an integer");
        this.Rule = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the ComboBox control? Should its selected value be validated too? In your example you can force validation by calling `RuleWrapper = RuleWrapper`, but I'm not sure that it is what you need.

Comment: The combox box selection triggers a different validation for the rule. So when I do RuleWrapper = RuleWrapper to force the validation in the code behind I get a ValidationException thrown but I do not know how to handle it so it gets displayed properly on the datagrid

Comment: I know how to force validation if I use the IDataErrorInfo or INotifyDataErrorInfo interfaces. What do you think if I completely rewrite this validation so that it is performed by those interfaces? You will have to rewrite all validation code then.

Comment: You should not have all that logic within a property set!

Comment: Its a wrapper to the actual property. Are you saying that I should create for each field a validate method instead of using the setter?

Comment: @vorrtex I do not mind writting the validation in another way. I have not fully implemented the solution I was waiting to get a way to implemented that would allow me to match all my validation requirement before proceeding. I have attempted the INotifyDataErrorInfo but the display was always in the validation summary and not with the nice looking red tool tips but if that is the only way please show me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to note (I'm still learning about validation, so I stand to be corrected).

- WPF doesn't support *ValidationException*.
- Setting *ValidatesOnExceptions=True* in a binding only handles
  exceptions in the internally used default converters (like converting a string to a
  number).
- Exceptions in your own converters aren't caught and cause your app
     to crash.
- Validation is handled using *IDataErrorInfo*, *INotifyDataErrorInfo (Silverlight and WPF 4.5)* and *[ValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.aspx)*

Also I'm answering from a WPF perspective at the moment.  I'll test on Silverlight later.

MSDN has a surprisingly good article here about [binding and validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Here's my sample which demonstrates a validation dependency between two text columns (for simplicity).  The second column is read-only but shows validation errors caused by the first column.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <Samples:DataGridValidationViewModels/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding Column1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding Column2, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I'm using MVVM Light for my view model/INotifyPropertyChange support, so replace my use of *Set(()=>...* with your own implementation (_prop = value; RaisePropertyChanged("string"); etc).

Note that raising a property changed event on a read-only property causes validation to happen on that property which is useful.

```
public class DataGridValidationViewModels
{
    public DataGridValidationViewModels()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<DataGridValidationViewModel>
                    {
                        new DataGridValidationViewModel(),
                        new DataGridValidationViewModel(),
                        new DataGridValidationViewModel(),
                        new DataGridValidationViewModel(),
                        new DataGridValidationViewModel(),
                        new DataGridValidationViewModel(),
                        new DataGridValidationViewModel(),
                    };

    }

    public IEnumerable<DataGridValidationViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class DataGridValidationViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public DataGridValidationViewModel()
    {
        _column1 = "Column 1";
        _column2 = "Column 2";
    }

    private string _column1;

    public string Column1
    {
        get { return _column1; }
        set
        {
            Set(() => Column1, ref _column1, value);
            Column2 = value;
        }
    }

    private string _column2;

    public string Column2
    {
        get { return _column2; }
        private set{ Set(()=>Column2, ref _column2, value);}
    }

    #region Implementation of IDataErrorInfo

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Column1":
                    return Column1 == "Error" ? "There's an error in column 1!" : string.Empty;

                case "Column2":
                    return Column1 == "Error" ? "There's an error in column 2!" : string.Empty;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When you change the text of Column 1 to "Error" you get:

[image]

Comment: This article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#exception has some useful info on DataGrid validation.  I may have to check my assertion that ValidationException doesn't work though :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer Phil I am reading over the links you provided.

Comment: Hey Phil, I followed your advices and went on and implemented the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface but I am still having issues see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670118/inotifydataerrorinfo-not-raising-error-changed-in-code-behind